# How to bring perforce client work space into sync with depot as of specific time of a specific date

Tags: perforce

I went through documentation of perforce. I can see we can bring the workspace 
    into sync with the depot as of midnight of a particular date, for example, p4 sync @2011/06/24 but I want to bring the workspace to a specific time of a particular date

Answer (score 2):

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/#CmdRef/filespecs.html#Using_revision_specifiers%3FTocPath%3DFile%2520Specifications%7C_____3

> **file@datespec**
>
> Date and time: The revision of file at the date and time specified.
>
> If no time is specified, the head revision at 00:00:00 on the morning
>   of the date specified is returned.
>
> **Dates are specified yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mm:ss or yyyy/mm/ddhh:mm:ss (with**
>   **either a space or a colon between the date and the time).**
>
> The datespec @now can be used as a synonym for the current date and
>   time.